# How to salvage questions closed by reasons that no longer apply?

Tags: support, closed-questions, reopen-closed

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182002/convert-big-endian-to-little-endian-in-c-without-using-provided-func) question about byte-swapping had been previous closed for the reason "Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved." However, this is no longer a close reason on SO.

Beyond the blatant lack of research, the question looks fine, and by the voting people have certainly found it useful. Granted, we may not need any more answers for it, but maybe 10 years down the road a new C standard will give us a better way to do it.

Is there a way to go about re-opening this?

Comment: It would likely be closed again as to broad.

Comment: While we are at it, here is another question that was closed for the same invalid reason and could be salvaged: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515135/triple-less-than-sign-in-bash

Comment: Use the meta effect to get reopen votes for it. Or, if you have 3k rep., vote to reopen and it gets put into a queue.